# GitHub Readme.md markdown file data-canonical-src issue with image src

Tags: github, automation, azure-functions, markdown, readme

I have an azure function that returns an image of my top blog from my feed. Now I have just added that function URL as the image src as below in the `Readme.md` file.

```
<img src="https://getlatestposts.azurewebsites.net/api/GetLatestPosts?code=VS4fy5DNxpj8/SUS0Chp0aGBux36c9OyOg5KhmSjh5dPVBvCaVaEuA==">
```

But the image is not loading at all, and when I check the HTML generated, I could see that the src is been updated with some weird URL from "https://camo.githubusercontent.com". There is also an additional `a tag` introduced.

[image]

Anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: You sure your image link is public? Because when I try it it throws "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request"

Comment: @Amacado Well, I gave a dummy URL here in SO. My original URL returns the base64 string, I am able to apply that manually to any image src, and it works fine.

Comment: please show us your markdown so we can reproduce it.. also a base64 sample would be nice

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://superuser.com/questions/1199393/is-it-possible-to-directly-embed-an-image-into-a-markdown-document

Comment: @Amacado I have updated the src with the actual function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix this issue. What I did is that, I returned a `File Stream` from my Azure Function, instead of returning a `base64` string. Below is my Azure function.

```
[FunctionName("GetLatestPosts")]
public static FileStreamResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest request, ILogger log) {
    try {
        var baseString = WriteOnImage(GetLatestFeeds());
        // Had to do this, as it was throwing error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character"
        string convert = baseString.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", String.Empty);
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(convert);
        var result = new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(bytes), Configuration.ContentType);
        log.LogInformation("Returning stream now!");
        request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate");
        return result;;
    } catch (System.Exception ex) {
        log.LogError($ "Something went wrong: {ex}");
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I did write an article about this entire application, you can read it [here](https://medium.com/@sibeeshvenu/show-recent-blog-posts-in-github-readme-using-azure-function-abceb9d5ce42?sk=fff4eb8dcd99af86acc7b93e8f354222). It contains the GitHub repositories too, just in case, if you are interested.